# MYSQL: how to select multiple values ​from one column to multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

i have problem with fine tuning my query, so I'm asking for help.

There are three tables:
1.Request:

| ID | User_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 209384 | 1000 |
| 209385 | 1001 |

2.equipment_type:

| ID | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stove |
| 2 | boiler |
| 3 | heater |

3.user_to_equipment_type:

| ID | User_ID | equipment_type_id | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 | Model1 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2 | Model2 |
| 3 | 1000 | 3 | Model3 |
| 4 | 1001 | 1 | Model4 |
| 5 | 1001 | 2 | Model5 |

I need to show everything about the equipment of one user in one line.
This is the part of the query that gets good results:

```
SELECT
request.id,
eqt.description as "type 1",
et.model as "model 1",
eqt2.description as "type 2",
et2.model as "model 2",
eqt3.description as "type 3",
et3.model as "model 3"

FROM
request,                     
equipment_type as eqt,             
equipment_type as eqt2,         
equipment_type as eqt3,         
user_to_equipment_type as et,     
user_to_equipment_type as et2,    
user_to_equipment_type as et3

WHERE
request.id = "209384" AND            
et.user_id = request.user_id AND
et2.user_id = request.user_id AND
et3.user_id = request.user_id AND
eqt.id = 1 AND
eqt2.id = 2 AND
eqt3.id = 3
```

and I get this result:

| ID | type 1 | model 1 | type 2 | model 2 | type 3 | model 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 209384 | stove | Model1 | boiler | Model2 | heater | Model3 |

But I don't like how much this request loads the system. Is there a way to make this less resource intensive?

index is on the user_id.

ps.

"Join" will only make things worse

pps.

I'm new to mysql, so I won't be able to clearly answer many clarifying questions.

Comment: Join will make things worse. False. You are actually using join with an implicit syntax (discouraged). You should use explicit joins and start narrowing down you issue.

Comment: Also have a look at pivot queries since this is the right name of what you are trying to achieve